# Getting id of parent parent element from import php call and external jquery file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to get the parent, parent id of a div from a button click. I have the main html where the element get imported via php. Here is the HTML Main page.

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION["account_name"]) || !isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) || !isset($_SESSION["role_id"])){
        header("Location: index.php");  
    }

    if(isset($_GET["page"])){
        $pageName = $_GET["page"];
    }
    else{
        $pageName = "websites";
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Link to CSS stylesheets -->
    <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- jQuery Hosted Library Link -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Set all php variable to be sent to onload file here
        var pagename = <?php echo json_encode($pageName); ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/onloads.js"></script>

    <title>Senneca Portal | Adminstration Panel</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php require_once("include/header.php"); ?>
    <section id="content">
        <section id="left-column">
            <img id="profile-img" src="<?php echo $_SESSION["profile_picture"]; ?>"/>
            <nav id="nav-side"></nav>
        </section>
        <section id="right-column">
            <div id="content-header">
                <button id="create">Add <?php echo $pageName; ?></button>
                <h2><?php echo $pageName; ?></h2>
                <?php 
                    if($pageName == "library" || $pageName == "products"){
                        echo "<select id='dd-website-select'>";
                            require_once("php/connection.php");

                            $sql = "SELECT website_id, website_name FROM websites ORDER BY website_id";

                            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            $stmt->bind_result($website_id, $website_name);

                            while($stmt->fetch()){
                                echo "<option value ='$website_id'>$website_name</option>";
                            }

                            mysqli_close($conn);
                        echo "</select>";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION["error"])){
                    echo "<p class='error-message'>".$_SESSION["error"]."</p>";
                    unset($_SESSION["error"]);
                }

                if(isset($_SESSION["success"])){
                    echo "<p class='success-message'>".$_SESSION["success"]."</p>";
                    unset($_SESSION["success"]);
                }
            ?>
            <div id="data"></div>
        </section>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have an imported jquery file called onloads.js

What is happening in this html is based on the page it is loading content to the div called data. It does this by using that variable pagename and sends it to the external.

Here is onloads.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Set active main nav tab
    var spgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    // Trim the url
    spgurl = trimToFileName(spgurl);

    var side = spgurl.substring(0, spgurl.indexOf('.php'));
    // Trim side url
    side = trimHashes(side);

    var suburl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    // Trim hashes out of sub url
    suburl = trimHashes(suburl);

    // Set active tab
    $("#nav-main ul li a").each(function(){
          if($(this).attr("href") === spgurl || $(this).attr("href") === ''){
            $(this).addClass("a-active");
          }
    });

    // Set the elements to fit window
    resizeDiv();

    // Load content
    loadSideNav(side, suburl);
    loadMainContent(pagename); // pagename set before this external file is loaded on page

    // Use AJAX to import form for creating items
    $(document).on('click', '#create', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "include/forms/create-"+pagename+"-form.php", success: function(result){
                $('#data').html(result);    
            }, error: function(){
                $('#data').html("<div class='not-found-container'><img class='not-found' src='images/icons/error.png'/><p>There was error processing your request please refresh and try again.</p></div>");    
            }
        });
    });

    // Use AJAX to import form for updating
    $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
        var item_id = $(this).parent().closest('div').attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "include/forms/update-"+pagename+"-form.php?update="+item_id, success: function(result){
                $('#data').html(result);    
            }, error: function(){
                $('#data').html("<div class='not-found-container'><img class='not-found' src='images/icons/error.png'/><p>There was error processing your request please refresh and try again.</p></div>");    
            }
        });
    });
});

// Resize the sections to fit to the window height
function resizeDiv(){
    var vph = $(window).height();
    vph = vph - 111;
    $('#left-column').css({'min-height': vph});
    $('#right-column').css({'min-height': vph});
}

 // Load side navigation
function loadSideNav(url, suburl){
    // Use AJAX to import sidebars navigation
    $.ajax({
        url: "include/nav-side-"+url+".php", success: function(result){
                $('#nav-side').html(result);

                $("#nav-side ul li a").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("href") === suburl || $(this).attr("href") === ''){
                    $(this).addClass("a-sub-active");
                }
            });
        }, error: function (){
            $('#nav-side').html("<p>An error has occurred importing the navigation.</p>");
        }
    }); 
 }

 // Load main content in right columnn
 function loadMainContent(pageName){
    // Use AJAX to import page main content
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/display-"+pageName+".php", success: function(result){
            $('#data').html(result);
        }, error: function (){
        // Change this to icon and a description
            $('#data').html("<p>No data to display.</p>");
        }
    });
 }

 // Trim all search criteria and hashes from url
 function trimToFileName(url){
     if(url.indexOf('?') > -1){
        url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('?'));
    }

    if(url.indexOf('#') > -1){
        url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('#'));
    }

    return url;
 }

 // Trim just hashes from url
 function trimHashes(url){
    if(url.indexOf('#') > -1){
        url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('#'));
    }

    return url;  
 }
```

What I am having trouble with is the document.on click, .edit portion of the onloads.js

It is not picking up the correct item_id on the call to gather the parent element. If I hard code a number into the variable it works fine but when I have it set to grab the id it does not have a value. How do I get this to grab the id?

Here is the form for better display php for the data of what I am grabbing.

```
while($stmt->fetch()){?>
            <div id="<?php $product_id ?>" class="website-container">
                <div class="controls-container">
                    <button class="delete"><img src="images/icons/delete.png"/></button>
                    <button class="edit"><img src="images/icons/edit.png"/></button>
                    <p>Edit/Delete</p>
                    <div class="cleared"></div>
                </div>
                <img class="display-website-img" src="<?php echo $product_img_link; ?>"/>
                <p class="website-name-display"><?php echo $product_display_name; ?></p>
                <p><span class="bolded">Model:</span><br/><?php echo $model; ?></p>
                <p><span class="bolded">Product Category:</span><br/><?php echo $product_category; ?></p>
                <p><span class="bolded">Product Sub Category:</span><br/><?php echo $product_sub_category; ?></p>
                <p><span class="bolded">Series:</span><br/><?php echo $product_series; ?></p>
                <p><span class="bolded">Website:</span><br/><?php echo $website; ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php }
```

I shortened this code it works but this is just to show you how its being displayed in the main html page.

Comment: because you're echoing a javascript object to to `pagename` variable and attempting to use `pagename` as a string, right after you declare pagename, do a `console.log(typeof pagename, pagename);` and see if it's storing correctly.

Comment: Its telling me "string products" just like it should be.

Comment: pagename isnt the problem. Its the click of the button class edit in the last section of code and retrieving the div id of the echo'd product_id. This probably needs to be json_encoded?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to use the parent().parent() instead of the parent().closest(). It works fine now. Weird that doesnt work the other way. Also the echo wasnt used in the id portion of the php which wasnt posting the id value in the first place but the parent().closest() still didnt work with that change.